# Using svg file under img Tag

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, svg

I am using ASP.NET mvc4 application, where .svg files will be placed under `/content/Images` folder.

Under `<img>` tag i Am trying to use `.svg` file as `src.`But this seems not working. But inline svg works fine. But my requirement demands it to be used under `<img>` tag. I have used proper MIME type also.

```
<img src=http://localhost:62987/Content/Images/simplest.svg />
```

Comment: unsing it under img Tag of html

Comment: This page: http://css-tricks.com/using-svg/ covers using svg in img tags and it looks pretty straighforward. What is the final markup for the img tag as it renders on the browser?

Comment: How have you verified that you've used the proper MIME type?  Where have you configured that?

Answer (score 0):

Its probably because you are missing the inverted commas around the `src`  attribute's path.

This syntax should work fine.

```
<img src="http://localhost:62987/Content/Images/simplest.svg" />
```

Check this working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s67Kk/) to demonstrate that the above mentioned method just works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Also check that your web server is serving your SVG files with the correct mime type.  It should be `image/svg+xml`.  An easy way to check is to look under the "Net" tab in your web browser development tools.